# elasticsearch-php 401 authentication fail

Tags: php, curl, elasticsearch, laravel-5

Using [elasticsearch-php](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php) on Laravel 5 through [Shift31/laravel-elasticsearch](https://github.com/shift31/laravel-elasticsearch) (provides facade for elasticsearch-php). Hosting an ES instance on [Facetflow](https://facetflow.com/).

config/elasticsearch.php:

```
return array(
    'hosts' => array(
        'https://accessUsername@ilovelasagna.east-us.azr.facetflow.io:443'
    )
);
```

WelcomeController.php:

```
public function elasticsearch()
{

    $searchParams['index'] = 'your_index';
    $searchParams['size'] = 50;
    $searchParams['body']['query']['query_string']['query'] = 'foofield:barstring';

    return Es::search($searchParams);
    // throws Authentication401Exception exception
}
```

**This returns Authentication401Exception**. My guess is the username is not passed to the Facetflow server, but I have not found a way to check if this is true.

The problem does not seem to be in the server's settings, because when I use plain curl, I get a 200 response:

```
public function justCurl()
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Now set some options (most are optional)

    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accessUsername@ilovelasagna.east-us.azr.facetflow.io:443");

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
    // returns 200 response
}
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facetflow's blazing-fast customer support pointed out the issue here.
Host was supposed to be marked as

```
'https://accessUsername:@ilovelasagna.east-us.azr.facetflow.io:443'
```

Note the colon after accessUsername.